# How to scale fit height fixed size child in the screen css only javascript allowed

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I have two child with fixed size:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="static_child">
  </div>
  <div class="static_child">
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.static_child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

I need to make this children responsive so they fit/fill the screen.

I can't change their fixed size.

I need to have both child to appear on the screen, by scaling down.
They should respond to bigger screen by growing appropriately.

http://codepen.io/eguneys/pen/zGbqqB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm reading your question right, but you could change the `width: 600px` to `width: 100%`. This way the width of your blocks will stretch to accommodate various screen sizes. The same does not seem to work for the height though. Hope this helped.

Comment: I said I can't change their fixed size.

Comment: Then it can't be done. by putting in ***px you're specifying a number of pixels, making the size static. If you change it to a percentage it becomes dynamic, adjusting to fit any screen size.